# Highlight text in verbatim environment

Tags: verbatim

I want to highlight a certain element in this matrix from matlab output. How can I do this in the `verbatim` environment?

```
\begin{verbatim}

P =

1.0000    0.7000         0         0         0
     0         0    0.5000         0         0
     0    0.3000         0    0.6500         0
     0         0    0.5000         0         0
     0         0         0    0.3500    1.0000
\end{verbatim}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The standard `verbatim` environment is too basic. You could use instead the [`listings`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/listings) package and its `escapeinside` feature to escape to LaTeX for the highlighting:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\lstset{
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  escapeinside=||
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
P =

 |\textcolor{cyan}{1.0000}|    0.7000         0         0         0
     0         0    0.5000         0         0
     0    0.3000         0    |\colorbox{magenta!30}{0.6500}|         0
     0         0    0.5000         0         0
     0         0         0    0.3500     |\textcolor{orange}{1.0000}|
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: There is a problem where the text to highlight contains math chars, such as _ (underscore)